# Error Generating Final Archive: java.io.IOException

Tags: eclipse

Error generating final archive: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect, Android Packaging Problem.

I've been recieving this error. and I cannot run my application.
Everyone encountered this? Please help me, what should I do? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is there any special character such as comma in your organization ? you have to remove such special characters